# Exchange email notifier?

Tags: email, ms-exchange

I do my coding work on an Ubuntu machine at work, but I keep a laptop running windows with outlook for the corporate email.  I don't really want to fight with Evolution and get it to work with the corporate setup, but I'd like something that could let me know on the Ubuntu machine if I got a new email in outlook/exchange.  Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short of a one-shot tool doing exactly what you want, I can recommend a 2-part approach:

1. [davmail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/) can help you connect to exchange server from Ubuntu (via Outlook web access or EWS)

   - Install using the .deb available on the [sourceforge site](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/download.html).
   - Follow the steps in [Linux Setup](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/linuxsetup.html) and [Getting Started](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/gettingstarted.html) pages to have davmail present an "IMAP interface to your exchange email". You would only need to configure IMAP port (un-check other things, unless you'd like to further experiment accessing email & calendar information via a linux client like Thunderbird)
2. [Conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/) can display unread messages on an imap inbox at any convenient location on your desktop. Alternatively, you can try [Popper](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/email-notification-in-ubuntu-popper/)

BTW, once you are past the (easy) configuration of davmail, you could access your outlook email from either Thunderbird or Evolution as if it were on a local IMAP server. [Thunderbird setup instructions](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/thunderbirdmailsetup.html) are available at the davmail site.

Comment: Had to install davmail from the download package, it's not in apt-get on my ubuntu setup.  It runs but never asks for credentials, so I don't think it's working.

Comment: It won't ask for credentials unless some client (like thunderbird, conky, popper) tries to read the email through IMAP. In this case it expects client to supply these creds - you can configure these at client side anyway. I have updated my answer to mention that davmail is not available via apt-get - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify for anyone who is confused by the instructions at the DavMail site, when you configure DavMail be sure to use the login and password for your account on the Exchange server, not on your machine at home.

Also, an easy way to display the mail count and subjects in Conky is to use [Kaivalagi's conkyEmailscript](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=869771).  Set the server to localhost and add the port number tag.

**Example from my conkyrc:**

```
${color6}${font LCDMono:style=regular:size=10} Exchange Server: ${color7}${font}${execi 600 conkyEmail  **--port=1143** --servertype=IMAP **--servername=localhost** --username=my-exchange-user-name --password=my-exchange-password --mailinfo=5}${font}
```